# How to select a word with keyboard when the cursor is on or adjacent to the word?

Tags: windows, keyboard, text-editing, selection

It is possible to select a single word by double-clicking on any part of the word.

With only my keyboard, is it possible to select a word when the cursor is on or adjacent to the word?

Comment: can you clarify? I don't understand what you mean by "word that is around cursor"

Comment: Double clicking on a word normally does select the entire word - that's the normal behaviour. What application are you running?

Comment: Maybe you want to use the keyboard, rather than the mouse, to make the selection?

Comment: I'm sorry I was in middle of writing and got interrupted and forgot to say about keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with the mouse you just double click as you said.

With the keyboard you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to jump one word at a time and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to select a word, while in conjunction pressing the arrow keys.

Comment: :) easy peasy :)

Comment: and if you want to be exact, you can use Shift + Keyboard arrows to select characters more precisely.

Comment: Technically, the answer is actually to use ctrl or ctrl+shift in conjunction with the arrow keys to jump or select words. Pressing ctrl or ctrl+shift by themselves wont do anything ;)

Comment: @Manachi: Technically incorrect, modifier keys modify the modification key state in the memory of your computer. ;-) While we're at it, our comments are already longer than just correcting the answer itself. :-)

Comment: With mouse you can double-clicking on ANY part of the word. With keyboard you need place cursor at start of word before use CTR+SHIFT+RIGHT. Basically need to press CTRL+LEFT to place cursor to beginning of word and then press CTR+SHIFT+RIGHT to select this word. Not so simple as just "double-clicking on any part of the word".

Comment: The solutions presented here are not smoothly, because the space at the end of the selected word is also selected. Unfortunately, this also happens when double-clicking (tested in Microsoft Word and Microsoft Excel). Does anyone know a solution for selecting the word without the space at the end?

Answer (score 0):

My solution requires two steps. If you first use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> arrow to get to the beginning of the word and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> arrow then you will get the word selected by only using the keyboard. I haven't found a one-step solution yet.